# number of consecutive character that not have regex form

Tags: java, regex

How can figure out the number of consecutive character that has not regex form.
For example, I have a text "youarenovalid21"
and regex is "(\d+)"
So we cannot elicit something up to character of 14 because the text has no number.
So I want to save the number of character that text has no regex form for this is 13.
Thanks.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Having a hard time understanding the question. Can you please add a few examples of what you wish to achieve in the question and perhaps the programming language you are using if applicable?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I’m downvoting and voting to close because you have been told your question is not clear and you have done nothing to clarify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To grab the text that is skipped by the regex, remember the initial position (`0`) / next position after previous regex match ([`m.end()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#end--)), then compare that to the start position of the match, as returned by [`m.start()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#start--).

*Example*

```
String input = "youarenovalid21";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(input);
int start = 0;
while (m.find()) {
    if (start < m.start())
        System.out.println("Not in regex: " + input.substring(start, m.start()));
    System.out.println("In regex: " + m.group());
    start = m.end();
}
if (start < input.length())
    System.out.println("Not in regex: " + input.substring(start));
```

*Output*

```
Not in regex: youarenovalid
In regex: 21
```

*Example 2*

```
String input = "1a22bb333ccc4444dddd";
```

*Output*

```
In regex: 1
Not in regex: a
In regex: 22
Not in regex: bb
In regex: 333
Not in regex: ccc
In regex: 4444
Not in regex: dddd
```

Alternatively, you make sure the regex will always grab everything:

```
String input = "1a22bb333ccc4444dddd";
for (Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\\D*)(\\d*)").matcher(input); m.find(); ) {
    if (m.start(1) < m.end(1))
        System.out.println("Not digits: " + m.group(1));
    if (m.start(2) < m.end(2))
        System.out.println("Digits: " + m.group(2));
}
```

*Output*

```
Digits: 1
Not digits: a
Digits: 22
Not digits: bb
Digits: 333
Not digits: ccc
Digits: 4444
Not digits: dddd
```